# How can I add attribute tags to an EF Core entity class in another class lib?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

Currently I have an ASP.NET project that uses Entity Framework Core for data access. I am using the third party library `HotChocolate` to host a GraphQL Server on top of the EF Core data model.

In HotChocolate I can use the `Authorize` attribute to control access to the data. E.g. the following entity is only to be accessed with users satisfying a certain policy that is configured during startup. The attribute can apply to either the class level or only to specific properties of the class.

If everything is in one project, this works fine. However, I'd like to separate concerns and move the data logic into a separate class library which I want to reference in the ASP.NET project. But the namespace `HotChocolate.Authorization` namespaces required for that the `Authorize` attribute lives in the ASP.NET project (which imports the HotChocolate dependency) and not in the class lib in which I'll move the EF Core logic. So I will have to remove that attribute.

Is there a way I can re-add in the ASP.NET layer?

I guess theoretically, I could also import the HotChocolate library also in the class lib for the EF Core model just to have access to its attributes, but somehow I have a feeling that this is not the way it is supposed to be.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "some-policy-name")]
public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: how about separate the [tag:HotChocolate] entirely from the data layer and have another class to represent the models in your app which enforces the `[Authorize]` attribute? and you can use automapper to tie them.

Comment: But afaik, the HocChocolate integration with EF Core requires for attributes to be set on the original EF Core entity classes. Though I am not 100% on that,

Comment: if it so, perhaps you can just reference [tag:hotchocolate] on both projects. its perfectly fine as long as the versions are compatible - its still best that they have the same version though.

Comment: this will be controversial, but I say... if it works, you don't touch it unless absolutely necessary. is there any particular reason why you want to move things around other than it being aesthetically less pleasing currently? to me it looks like you are wasting valuable time.

Comment: I have thought about it and have made some changes so I could separate the data logic into a different class lib. With Hot Chocolate in my API project I can reference this classlib and configure authz outside of the attributes:

`public class OrganisationType : ObjectType<Organisation>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Organisation> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Authorize();
    }
}`